# tkinter Text.get() raises a TypeError exception

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def save_d():
    files = open("mp3list.txt","a")
    files.write("title :\n")
    files.write("%s" % lists.get())
    files.write("appraisal :\n")
    files.write("%s\n" % appraisal.get())
    lists.delete(0,END)
    appraisal.delete("1.0",END)

def read_f(file):
    lists = []
    lists_f = open(file)
    for line in lists_f:
        lists.append(line.rstrip())
    return lists

app = Tk()
app.title(" MP3 Player " )

Label(app,text = "lists:").pack()
lists = StringVar()
lists.set(None)
options = read_f("mp3.txt")
OptionMenu(app,lists,*options).pack()

Label(app,text = "appraisal:").pack()
appraisal = Text(app)
appraisal.pack()

Button(app,text = "Save",command = save_d).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\J\Desktop\mp3.py", line 8, in save_d
    files.write("%s\n" % appraisal.get())
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'
```

Why does the error occur? How can I fix this?

Comment: `File "C:\Users\J\Desktop\mp3.py", line 8, in save_d`, `get() missing 1 required positional argument`.  Sounds like `.get()` needs an argument passed to it.

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass the `Text.get()` function a start and stop index indicating what part of the text in the `Text` widget you want.

If you want to get all the text in the `Text` widget, you can use

```
appraisal.get('1.0', END)
```

([Documentation for `Text.get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.get-method))

Comment: For the pedants, `get` only *requires* a start index.  If the stop index is omitted, only a single character following the start index is returned.

Comment: I'm curious - do you know why it is that you must put the number in single quotes, and with a decimal place? Why not just put appraisal.get(1,2)?