# Tkinter Text Widget Error

Tags: python, tkinter

When i enter the text value in the Text Box and click on generate Button in the GUI Form generated from this Code it does not print the desired output, Instead I get the below error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
   return self.func(*args)
 File "/Users/Desktop/tk.py", line 28, in <lambda>
   b1 = Button(root, text='Generate', command=(lambda e=ents: 
fetch(e)))
 File "/Users/Desktop/tk.py", line 7, in fetch
   text  = text[1].get()
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'
```

## CODE

```
from tkinter import *
fields = 'Section1','Section2'    

def fetch(entries):
   for text in entries:
      field = text[0]
      text  = text[1].get()
      print('%s \n%s\n' % ("\n====================================\n" + field + "\n====================================\n", text))    

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=35, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Text(row, height=10)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=15, pady=15)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries    

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.title('Form')
   #Text.get()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1 = Button(root, text='Generate', command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you read any documentation on the text widget? The parameters to the `get` method are well documented.

Comment: Basically a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49207867/291641

Comment: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html

Comment: Read the text Wiget Documentation linked here and the issue is resolved, I used text  = text[1].get('1.0', 'end') and it solved the issue, Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tkinter Text.get() raises a TypeError exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999033/tkinter-text-get-raises-a-typeerror-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the text Wiget Documentation and the issue is resolved, 
I used the index parameters in get method

CURRENT:

```
text  = text[1].get()
```

MODIFY

```
text = text[1].get('1.0', 'end')
```